# Questions about creating an RSS reader

Tags: rss

I am really green to this and came across this site by googling the subject. I am looking to create my own rss reader. I am wondering what language would be best to create a custom rss reader in the same lines as Google reader? I wonder what language do they use. Any and all help or direction pointing or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be more specific

I have not used google reader but you can make an rss reader in any language, choose which best suits you.

Comment: So no specific language is better suited for a rss reader? When you say more specific what should I be including that I am not? Thanks again for the help.